# can not open include file expat.h GDAL? How to setup expat XML library?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, open-source, gdal

While setting up GDAL Project, I am stuck with an error

> Can not open include file "expat.h". No such file or directory.

[image: error]

It is because ogr_expat.cpp has included in code

> # include < expat.h >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. Just sharing for knowledge.

Download and Install XML Library in C Drive

[image]

and give its path in include directories via View.Propery Manager.

> C:\Expat-2.0.0\Source\lib